# Lambda as an argument to a method

Tags: java, lambda

Understandably a Lambda can be passed as an argument where the expected parameter is a type of a functional interface.

My question is:
Is it possible to pass a Lambda as an argument where the type is **not** a functional interface? (If yes then please provide an example)

Comment: You can pass it to a method that accepts an `Object` if you like.

Comment: No, it's not possible, and what would be the point?